# How would I go about adding a Radio Button to a popup menu?

Tags: java, swing, checkbox, awt, popupmenu

I want to have a `TrayIcon` have a `java.awt.PopupMenu`. I already know how do this part. But it appears that Java doesn't have a `RadioButtonMenuItem`.
I already tried to add a `JRadioButtonMenuItem` to it, but that resulted in many errors.
Is there a way that I could incorporate 3 "checkboxes" that do not allow more than 1 to be selected at a time and add it to my `PopupMenu`?

Comment: Is there any reason why you're using AWT and not Swing? Swing does contain what you're looking for: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/JRadioButtonMenuItem.html

Comment: JRadioButtonMenuItem is a Swing class, it's not going to work well in the AWT interface.  As berry says, why not use Swing for the whole thing?

Comment: Because the `new TrayIcon(String title, ImageIcon icon, Popup popup)` method only allows for a `java.awt.PopupMenu`, not a `javax.swing.JPopupMenu`. Trust me, I have already tried.

Comment: @JavaCoder-1337 you can add all JComponents to the JMenu or to the JPopupMenu as you want (JComboBox as JMenuItem in the JPopupMenut has the Bug), ane as there mentioned for todays code is required using Swing JComponents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice would be to use Swing - there's no reason I can see for using old AWT menus here. True `TrayIcon` is part of `java.awt`, but there is code around (see [here](http://forums.dzone.com/java/3169-java-awt-trayicon-javax-swing-jpopupmenu.html)) that works fine for me to integrate a swing menu with a TrayIcon.

And of course, once you're in swing territory you're away, just use `JRadioButtonMenuItem`.

Comment: this link is broken now